# Stylus break on syntax error similar to less

Tags: css, stylus

I'm testing stylus and I'm surprised that the compiler transforms almost everything I type like:

```
mivar = blackredgrenn

body
    margin 0f 
    background-color #323242342332423123     

        werewers
            color red  
            &:first-child
                color mivar

            whatever assa hj
```

into

```
body{margin:0 f;}
body background-color #323242342332423123 werewers{color:#f00;whatever:assa hj}
body background-color #323242342332423123 werewers:first-child{color:blackredgrenn}
```

Is this the way it should work? is there any option to make the compiler to stop and show error like in less? I'm compiling with grunt, is the common practice to run afterwards csslint to spot there the errors? what alternative do we have?

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no option to show errors, as this code is not an error as Stylus sees it.

Stylus' syntax is very flexible now, and it is based on indents, this way you can't write some properties after other ones with an increased indent, as Stylus would interpret then the first part with lesser indent as a selector (that's what happens in your example), and as CSS could always get new properties, there is no list of “known” properies, so `whatever` is also printed as is.

If you're not sure you're writing a proper indented code, then the best option is either to use a linter to check CSS validity, or to write everything in CSS syntax using curly braces and semicolons.